# How many elements can a Stack store in Java?

Tags: java, stack, element

Is there a maximum number of elements that can be stored in a stack? Is the only limitation the amount of storage available to the system?

For clarity, I'm referring to `java.util.Stack`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are taling about `java.util.Stack`, then the limit is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is about 2 billion. However if you let it grow naturally, you get an exception if you add more than about 1.3 billion (10 * 2^28) as it will try to grow the underlying array to a size larger than is allowed.

IMHO Stack is a legacy class replaced in Java 1.2 (1998) I don't suggest you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm a CS student; due to the direction of the coursework, I cannot yet avoid them. Out of curiosity, what replaced Stack?

Comment: AFAIK, `java.util.ArrayList` which is an unsynchronized version which wraps an array and implements standard interfaces such as `List`. The earlier collections where not designed to implement interfaces which is why they have multiple methods which do the same thing for compatibility.

Comment: @DJClayworth, ArrayList has `add()` and `remove(size()-1)` which do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The storage capability is normally limited by memory available, either heap memory for stack data structures or stack memory for the call stack.

Comment: ...maximum memory available, or Integer.MAX number of items?

Comment: @Chii It depends on the implementation of the stack, which could also use long indices. I'd say you're likely to hit the memory constraint before hitting the maximum index range.